# Сайт на MODX HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: .htaccess, url, modx

Сайт roural.ru при загрузке страниц с шаблонами "Родительский каталог" и "Каталог" вылазит ошибка HTTP ERROR 500.
Пример: http://roural.ru/oborudovanie-benza.html

При этом страницы с шаблоном "окончательная конечная" открываются нормально с ответом 200.
Пример: http://roural.ru/nasos-perekachki-masla-benza-11.html

Вложенность такая:
[image: Вложенность такая]

Что пробовал делать:
В настройках хостинга менял версию php, все перепробовал с 5.6-7.4   Сейчас php 7.4
Пробовал разные настройки .htaccess стоковый тоже пробовал с минимальными настройками
Кеш чистил, в админке и физически удалял все в папке cache

Сейчас htaccess  такой

```
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag ignore_repeated_errors off
php_flag ignore_repeated_source off
php_flag report_memleaks on
php_flag track_errors on
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
php_value error_log /home/t/toppropv/roural.ru/public_html/PHP_errors.log
php_value error_reporting 2047
php_value log_errors_max_len 0

<Files PHP_errors.log>
    Require all denied
</Files>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.roural.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://roural.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*more=1.*
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L,NC]

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

php_flag register_globals Off

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
    </filesMatch>
</ifModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://roural.ru/ [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.htm\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ http://roural.ru/ [R=301,L]
```

В чем тут дело?

Вот как выглядят настройки URLs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробовал поочередно вкл\выкл планины, думал может быть дело в каком то одном. Но нет, проблема осталась

Comment: В логе такие ошибки

[2022-09-29 00:59:15] (ERROR @ /home/t/toppropv/roural.ru/public_html/core/model/modx/modcachemanager.class.php : 344) Error caching lexicon topic lexicon/en/core/source
[2022-09-29 01:02:20] (ERROR @ /home/t/toppropv/roural.ru/public_html/core/model/modx/modcachemanager.class.php : 344) Error caching lexicon topic lexicon/en/core/default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А с чего все началось? или никогда не работали эти страницы? Лучше всего обновиться до 2.8 версии, у староватый MODX для версии PHP 7.4. Также проблемные шаблоны можно попробовать облегчить - отключить все плагины разом, все сниппеты, и по очереди включать, тем самым локализуя проблему. Да, конечно нужно привести к актуальным версиям текущие пакеты.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло изменение на хостинге версии php на 5.5 но учтите что например в бегете, там можно в выпадающем списе в интерфейсе выбрать версию, но ребут хостинга происходит раз в 10-15 мин, после ребута изменения вступают в силу